# Expected Number of Iterations in Perfect Hashing

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, hash-function

We know that we can do [Perfect Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) in expected linear time using a well-known two-level hash table approach. But what is the expected number of iterations that we do to construct the first level, *only*, of the hash table? The first level – the one where we are trying to find a hash function so that the squared lengths of the collision chains, $m_i^2$, in the buckets on the first level in linear.

I know how to prove that the expected number of iterations is constant for the construction of the second level, where we have $m_i^2$ places for $m_i$ elements but I'm not sure about the first level only.

Comment: There seems to be a typo near "in linear"?

Comment: The Wikipedia article that you link to doesn't mention iterations. It links to a paper behind a paywall that presumably contains more details. You should describe the algorithm in sufficient detail to make the question self-contained.